# import selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar but can't use APIs(setBinary，setExperimentalOption)with EdgeOptions

Tags: java, selenium-edgedriver

For the Chromium-Edge (version 80 or later), we should treat it as an Edge browser.So I got the selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar ,but When I import it,I still can't use api such as setExperimentalOption with EdgeOptions.What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: any update on this, i am having the same issue.